# How to convert multiple GIFs into one PDF on OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line, macos-mojave

I found the following code to do it with one GIF:

```
sips -s format pdf cat.gif --out 'cat.pdf'
```

I understand that I can use `for` and do it for multiple files. But I will get multiple PDFs in result, but I want to combine all GIFs into single pdf.

How can I do it?